# How to prevent influence in an area without using an extra armature bone?

Tags: modeling, rigging, weight-painting

Trying to prevent influence in a certain area with a character I'm rigging. How would I prevent the influence of the arm bone interact with the area near the chest and chest bone, as the arm bone is stretching the chest area way too much.

Example of the chest being stretched by the influence of the arm bone:
[image]

Example of the chest not being stretched due to adding an extra bone, but it creates an area of influence that shouldn't really be there (the little hole circled in red):
[image]

Is there a way to create the outcome of the 2nd example but without using an extra bone to prevent the influence of the arm bone stretching the chest area?

Comment: Of course. You can adjust the bone influences manually in Weight Paint mode.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using automatic weights? The vertices of a mesh are controlled by the data in a vertex group, assigned to each specific bone. In order to change the amount of influence a bone has over specific vertices, you should learn weight painting. It's not too hard, there's plenty of tutorials all over youtube for it. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SCWZr-It1bE) is a good, simple introduction into weight painting.

Comment: Yes, I used automatic weights. It looks like I do need to learn weight painting, thank you.